# bash: sed: command not found... in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, command

when I try this code for GATE installation:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/xincao/GATE/2.4.1.2/-install/bin:/home/xincao/GATE/2.4.1.2-install/include
```

Then the error shows:

```
bash: sed: command not found...
```

I never met this problem before, anyone can help?
Any answer will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: what is your `env` output?  If you have a plain install of Centos 7, then `sed` should be in `/usr/bin/sed`

Comment: @richyen Hi, do you mean run env in the terminal of home directory? There is no sed in output. By the way, could you tell me how to input env like you with code mode in comment, I am a rookie here. Thank you very much!

Comment: maybe you can share output of `env`? Yes, just type “env” into your terminal, and copy/paste the output. What I’m really interested in is actually the value of `$PATH`, which you can copy/paste the output of entering `echo $PATH` into your terminal

Comment: @richyen Hi, thanks to your quick respond, I really appreciate it!! What I mean before is how to input env with a gray background highlighting it as a code like you, lol. I tried that export code in the terminal of my home directory but not some specific building directory for installation. Then it works, is that the point I neglect before? Do I have to update my enviromental variables always in home directory terminal?

Comment: To get the preformatted look, you just need to use backticks ` ` `.  One backtick around your text for single-line.  Three backticks around a code block.  Cheers!

Comment: @richyen Thanks a lot for that! Would you mind answer the question I menstioned in last comment?